# EJBs are getting duplicated in weblogic 12c using EAR deployment from jdeveloper 12c

Tags: ejb, ejb-3.0, weblogic12c, jdeveloper, ejb-3.1

My project consists of 2 modules webapp + jar(ejb module), when I tried to run this app from jdeveloper 12c deployed to integrated weblogic server, the server is identifying all ejb beans as twice, one from war and other from jar. Any guess how this happens?

Answer (score 1):

If your application is deployed as EAR, the EAR probably contains the EJB JARs within the WAR and the EAR.
If not, you are probably deploying the WAR with the EJB JARs inside AND the EJB JARs at the same time as multiple deployment.